# How to $_GET php variable in url

Tags: php, get, url-parameters

I have this PHP code and trying to get the value of the variable `language` from the url parameters when specified link is clicked.

How do I do this? The code below only gets the value of `Java` in the first statement and not the values in the `elseif` statements.

```
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {

    if ($_GET['language'] = 'Java') {
        $q = 'title:(Java+Developer)';
    }
    elseif ($_GET['language'] = 'PHP') {
        $q = 'title:(PHP+Developer)';
    }
    elseif ($_GET['language'] = 'JavaScript') {
        $q = 'title:(JavaScript+Developer)';
    }
}
```

Links:

```
      <li><a href="programming/?language=Java">Java</a></li>
      <li><a href="programming/?language=PHP">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="programming/?language=JavaScript">JavaScript</a></li>
```

Comment: It's not `$_GET['language'] = 'Java'`. It should be `$_GET['language'] == 'Java'`

Comment: Its `==` for comparison

Comment: you're right! My mistake! Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between `=` and `==`. One is for assigning, the other for comparing.

In your first `if()` statement, you're assigning the value `Java` to `$_GET['language']`, which will evaluate to `Java`. This will then be true.

Change the single `=` in the comparisons to `==`, and you should be all set.

Comment: +1 for evaluating to `true` making the `if` valid

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single equals sign. This is an assignment (as you do when defining a variable).

You need to use double equals signs `==`. This is how you test equality.

```
$_GET['language'] == SOME_STRING
```

In addition, I would recommend using a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of multiple `if` statements:

```
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'language' ] ) ) {
  switch( $_GET[ 'language' ] ){
    case "Java":
      $q = 'title:(Java+Developer)';
    break;
    case "PHP":
      $q = 'title:(PHP+Developer)';
    break;
    case "JavaScript":
      $q = 'title:(JavaScript+Developer)';
    break;  
  }
}
```

Using a `switch` statement will make this code much easier to maintain and also to add extra conditions (other languages).

Comment: Would it be better to use "===" to also check the data type that is being received or is it that only strings are passed?

Comment: @KartikA - I always promote explicit code - so using a strict equality operator would be a good idea. However, with my switch case example, it is not needed.

Comment: Hey sorry just saw your code, in your code it shall not be necessary I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Check the equal sign! Replace "=" with "=="

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

if (isset($_GET['language'])) {

```
    if ($_GET['language'] == 'Java') {
    $q = 'title:(Java+Developer)';
    }
    elseif ($_GET['language'] == 'PHP') {
    $q = 'title:(PHP+Developer)';
    }
    elseif ($_GET['language'] == 'JavaScript') {
    $q = 'title:(JavaScript+Developer)';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value `Java` to `$_GET["language"]` which always returns true. You must compare the value of `$_GET["language"]` against a string. Compare using `==` or `===` operator.

```
if ($_GET["language"] === "Java") { 
  /* here be dragons */ 
}
```

It is also good habit to use [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to catch this kind of errors.

```
if ("Java" === $_GET["language"]) { 
  /* here be dragons */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "=" here which is for assigning the variable some value.
Have a look at the use of these:

1. "=" is used for assigning a value to some variable.
2. "==" is used for comparison (regardless of the data type). For example if

> $var =1 and we evaluate a condition
>
> if($var == TRUE )

The result will be bool True because TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0 always.

3.
"===" comparison based on datatype also. The above condition will evaluate to Bool False because the data types are different.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: It would be better to add some explanations about your answer.